# How to encode Hex representation of bytes as Python byte values?

Tags: python, byte

The below values are Hex representations of bytes, ie. `41` at the top left is 'A'. How can I convert all values to Python bytes, i.e. `41` would become `b\x41`.

```
41 61 30 41 61 31 41 61
32 41 61 33 41 61 34 41
61 35 41 61 36 41 61 37
41 61 38 41 61 39 41 62
30 41 62 31 41 62 32 41
62 33 41 62 34 41 62 35
41 62 36 41 62 37 41 62
38 41 62 39 41 63 30 41
```

In a next step, I would take the string of Python encoded bytes, `s = b'\x41\x61\30...'` and write a binary file from it:

```
f = open("binary", "wb")
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

It would also solve my problem, if the values could be somehow converted to bytes directly without the intermediate Python encoding.

Comment: How your hex variable currently stored?

Comment: As ASCII in a text file

Comment: In your case, is there anything wrong with using `chr(int(str(<hex_num>),16))`? It is a clunky solution though

Comment: Looks like `binascii.a2b_hex(b'10')` is doing what I mean.

Comment: Gotcha. If you need to do any processing of the raw binary, it makes sense to use `binascii` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment above, I think the best way to achieve this would be to rely on the built-in python functions `int()` and `chr()`. Although it's not a one-function-call solution, it will do the trick in not very much code.

Given a file (call it `hex.txt`) of space-separated hex values, you might do the following:

```py
with open("hex.txt") as f, open("chars.txt") as g:
    for str_hex in f.read().split(" "):
        g.write(chr(int(str_hex, 16)))
```

*Edit:* See @Mark_Ransom's comment below for limitations to this solution.

Comment: It's unclear from the question whether each value should become a character or a byte. For values less than 0x80 there won't be a difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom Please allow me to clarify the question in this comment: With "How can I convert all values to Python bytes, i.e. 41 would become b\x41" I really just mean that a `b'\x'` should be prepended to the hex byte value. If the hex value consists of only one hex digit, then it should be prepended by `b'\x0'`.

Comment: @TMOTTM on re-reading your question it's not as unclear as I thought. You can make this code perfect by replacing `chr(int(str_hex, 16))` with `bytes([int(str_hex, 16)])`.